# What is Cumulus?

Tags: polkadot, cumulus

How does Cumulus relate to Polkadot? What is the difference between the two?

Can I launch a chain without Cumulus? Are there any good documentation around the interactions between the two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably an oversimplification, but you can think of [Cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus) as a set of tools which allows you to convert a solo-chain Substrate blockchain into a Polkadot compatible Parachain.

More specifically, it provides libraries for all of the necessary parts of the Polkadot protocol necessary for Parachains to work, for example:

- Creating new parachain blocks via Collators
- Listening to the relay chain for updates
- Synchronizing upgrades between the parachain and relay chain
- etc...

These are all parts that are specific to being a parachain, so all of those things exist in the separate Cumulus repository, while Substrate focuses on just the general development of blockchains, independent of the Polkadot Protocol.

Comment: It should be said that unless you're switching out the consensus mechanism, then it's usually not too hard to turn a self-sovereign substrate chain into becoming a parachain.

Comment: Is it therefore fair to say that i start with substrate and when the time comes I add cumulus or do I run into problems if i don't start with cumulus from day 1?